# check trusted certificate with openssl

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, xmpp, libstrophe

I developp a xmpp client using libmesode(fork libstrophe).
I want to secure the authentication with certification.
the server side has a certificate server.pem
the client side has its certificate client.pem

in lidmesode the functions used to check the certificate:

```
tls_t *tls_new(xmpp_ctx_t *ctx, sock_t sock, xmpp_certfail_handler certfail_handler, char *tls_cert_path)
{
    _xmppctx = ctx;
    _certfail_handler = certfail_handler;
    _cert_handled = 0;
    _last_cb_res = 0;
    tls_t *tls = xmpp_alloc(ctx, sizeof(*tls));

    if (tls) {
        int ret;
        memset(tls, 0, sizeof(*tls));

        tls->ctx = ctx;
        tls->sock = sock;
        tls->ssl_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());
        if (tls->ssl_ctx == NULL)
            goto err;

        SSL_CTX_set_client_cert_cb(tls->ssl_ctx, NULL);
        SSL_CTX_set_mode(tls->ssl_ctx, SSL_MODE_ENABLE_PARTIAL_WRITE);
        SSL_CTX_set_verify(tls->ssl_ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, verify_callback);
        if (tls_cert_path) {
            SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(tls->ssl_ctx, NULL, tls_cert_path);
            //SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(tls->ssl_ctx, certif, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
        }
        tls->ssl = SSL_new(tls->ssl_ctx);
        if (tls->ssl == NULL)
            goto err_free_ctx;

        ret = SSL_set_fd(tls->ssl, sock);
        if (ret <= 0)
            goto err_free_ssl;
    }

    return tls;

err_free_ssl:
    SSL_free(tls->ssl);
err_free_ctx:
    SSL_CTX_free(tls->ssl_ctx);
err:
    xmpp_free(ctx, tls);
    _tls_log_error(ctx);
    return NULL;
} 

static int
verify_callback(int preverify_ok, X509_STORE_CTX *x509_ctx)
{
    const STACK_OF(X509) *sk = X509_STORE_CTX_get1_chain(x509_ctx);
    int slen = sk_X509_num(sk);
    unsigned i;
    X509 *certsk;
    xmpp_debug(_xmppctx, "TLS", "STACK");
    for(i=0; i<slen; i++) {
        certsk = sk_X509_value(sk, i);
        _print_certificate(certsk);
    }
    xmpp_debug(_xmppctx, "TLS", "ENDSTACK");

    if (preverify_ok) {
        sk_X509_pop_free(sk, X509_free);
        printf("=========> 1\n");
        return 1;
    } else if (_cert_handled) {
        if (_last_cb_res == 0) {
            X509_STORE_CTX_set_error(x509_ctx, X509_V_ERR_APPLICATION_VERIFICATION);
        }
        sk_X509_pop_free(sk, X509_free);
        return _last_cb_res;
    } else {
        int err = X509_STORE_CTX_get_error(x509_ctx);
        const char *errstr = X509_verify_cert_error_string(err);
        xmpp_debug(_xmppctx, "TLS", "ERROR: %s", errstr);

        X509 *user_cert = sk_X509_value(sk, 0);
        struct _tlscert_t *tlscert = _x509_to_tlscert(_xmppctx, user_cert);
        int cb_res = 0;
        if (_certfail_handler) {
            cb_res = _certfail_handler(tlscert, errstr);
        }
        xmpp_conn_free_tlscert(_xmppctx, tlscert);

        _cert_handled = 1;
        _last_cb_res = cb_res;

        if (cb_res == 0) {
            X509_STORE_CTX_set_error(x509_ctx, X509_V_ERR_APPLICATION_VERIFICATION);
        }

        sk_X509_pop_free(sk, X509_free);
        return cb_res;
    }
}
```

when the xmpp client connect to the ejabbed xmpp server with TLS, openssl check the server certificate that is self signed but continue to connect !!.
the second thing is: the openssl doesn't check the server certificate with the client certificate to check of the server certificate is trusted or no.

is openssl do these check ?

1) disconnect if self signed certificate

2) check if certificate is trusted.

the following capture show that the server send the certificate
and then the client send the key.

is this key should be taken from client certification !

[image]

Comment: Also see [SSL/TLS Client](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client) and [Hostname Validation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/hostname_validation) on the OpenSSL wiki.